# How do I find my home servers IP address?

Tags: server, ip-address

I have installed Nginx webserver on my system. I just need to know the IP adress of the server which am running. I have Googled many times but I didn't get a good answer.

Comment: Can you give us more detail on what you tried? Have you tried whois or nslookup for example? Also, it may help to know other details such as host, registrar, and domain name.

Comment: i have setup ngix on my system..and i just need to know the ip adress of the homeserver in which am running

Comment: Just google "What is my ip" and google will tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows, use the command line and enter `ipconfig`.

If on Linux, enter `ifconfig` from the terminal to find out your ip address.  I believe it's `ifconfig` on Mac too.

Comment: well am on windows ..i have tried ipconfig ..and i get lots of ip address information like IPV4 adress,subnet gateway etc ..and i have found dns address ..is that my home server ip ??

Comment: IPv4 is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your information ..have you ever tried round robin dns with ngix

Comment: No I haven't, I work mostly on the programming end of things :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you get lost or forget the cmd command use this link:

http://ip-lookup.net/

The WAN address is your External IP

&

The LAN address is your internal IP on that particular machine.

P.S. - for the foreseeable future look for IPv4, IPv6 is estimated not to take over IPv4 for a long time.

Hope this helps :)